# What is ACTIVITY ID in Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

What is this activity ID in CosmosDB? Usually I get a GUID while writing any wrong query in Query explorer in Cosmos DB.
[image]

I did a little bit of R&D on this and did not find enough information, and thus have posted this question.

Comment: That’s just a reference to your execution of the query. It's not a stored property. You have an error in your query but without being able to see what the query is, there is no way to know what the error is.

Answer (score 1):

> What is this activity ID in CosmosDB?

This is a unique identifier for the operation. It can be used for tracing execution of Cosmos DB requests. Even you don't get wrong query, the activity id  still exists in your request.
If you query Azure Cosmos DB resources using the REST API, you also could see this value in response header.
For more details, you could read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/querying-documentdb-resources-using-the-rest-api).